# Linear Algebra: Prove/disprove diagonalizability given a minimum polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the statement that I am to prove/disprove:

> If the minimum polynomial of $A$ is $A^5 = 5 A^2$, then $A$ is not
>   diagonalizable.

First, I'm confused about how this can actually be a minimum polynomial. From my understanding, the minimum polynomial is a specific polynomial of least degree which $A$ satisfies. But, couldn't I just multiply both sides of that equation by $A^{-2}$? Then the minimum polynomial would be $A^3 - 5I = 0$, which is of lesser degree. That's really confusing for me!!

Anyway, I continue with this problem focusing on the given polynomial. I know that $A$ is at least 5x5, because the minimum polynomial is of degree 5. However, there are only two distinct roots of the minimum polynomial:

$$A^5 - 5A^2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow A^2 (A^3 - 5I) = 0 \Longrightarrow$$ eigenvalues: $0,\,5^{1/3}$.

Is that correct? If there were 5 distinct roots, and I knew $A$ were exactly 5x5, then this question would be cake, and it's definitely diagonalizable. Instead, all I know is that there are only 2 eigenvalues, which does not necessarily mean that these are no more than 2 eigenvectors, so $A$ may or may not be diagonalizable (e.g., when looking at roots of $I$).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using A as an unknown for polynomials? Or is it a matrix?

Comment: I think we can assume that what's meant is that the minimum polynomial of $A$ is $t^5-5t^2$.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as this: if a matrix is diagonalizable, then its minimal polynomial is simply $\prod(x-\lambda)$ over the distinct eigenvalues, so it can't have repeated roots?

Comment: You can't multiply by $A^{-2}$ unless $A$ is actually invertible, which in this case it's not.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Buy, an identity matrix of size n has fewer than n roots and is diagonalizable (already diagonalized, obviously).

Comment: @GregMartin, how can you tell from the given information that it's not invertible?

Comment: @Clark, I think Gerry meant *the minimal polynomial* can't have repeated roots, and that's correct, as a matrix is diagonalizable iff its min. pol. is a product of different linear factors.

Comment: @Clark, the matrix is not invertible since zero is one of its eigenvalues...

Comment: Why was this question voted down!

@DonAntonio, thanks. Sorry, I'm still learning about eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @Clark: I think it'd be a good idea if you'd clean your post: first, note that both me and other poster were confused as to what you meant was the minimal polynomial. Second, you focus on the eignevalues of $\,x^5-5x^2\,$ yet you continue to write $\,A\,$ instead of $\,x\,$...this is confusing.

Comment: Clark, the minimal polynomial of the identity matrix is $x-1$, which is $\prod(x-\lambda)$ over the distinct eigenvalues, of which there is only one. The minimal polynomial has no repeated roots, consistent with my comment.

Comment: The polynomial has FOUR distinct roots $x=0,\,x=\sqrt[3]{5}$ and $-\frac{\sqrt[3]{5}}{2}+(or\,-)\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{5}$ . Zero has multiplicity two. It is the multiplicity of zero which destroys the diagonalizability!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant (a guess) that $\,m_A(x):=x^5-5x^2\,$ is the minimal polynomial of a matrix $\,A\,$, then since $\,m_A(x)=x^2(x^3-5)\,\,,\,\,A$ is not diagonalizable since it is not the product of different linear factors (never mind whether the field of definition of $\,A\,$ contains or not the roots of the factor $\,x^3-5\,$).

Diagonalization does not depend on the number of different eigenvalues a matrix has but whether there are as many linearly independent eigenvectors of the matrix as its order, or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known criterion for diagonalizability. A matrix A is diagonalizable

if and only if its minimum polynomial is of the form

$P_{min}(x)=(x-\lambda _{1})(x-\lambda _{2})...(x-\lambda _{k})$

where $\lambda_{1},..\lambda _{k}$ its discrete eigenvalues. It is clear that in

your problem A does not satisfy that criterion and hence it is NOT diagonalizable!!